# How to display editorOverviewRuler.inlineChatInserted and inlineChatRemoved on the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been working on creating a vscode custom theme extention.

I know how to change properties color, but sometimes I confuse with showing changed colors on editor.
I have been looking for the position displayed two properties `editorOverviewRuler.inlineChatInserted` and `editorOverviewRuler.inlineChatRemoved`.

If you know these position to display on editor, please let me know!

Thank you!

Comment: what is "position to displayed"?

Comment: if you don't know when/where these colors are used, leave them the default by not defining them in your theme file

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant the position or place where I customized the property's color. @starball

Comment: Thank you for your help! I decided to do so on your advice. @rioV8